# Pull image vs. Git pull

Tags: docker

I am currently working on a production release pipeline and am asking myself why are people even using container registries to build and push their images when they could also pull the whole repository and run compose up?

Don't get me wrong, I know that docker is perfectly for setting up equal environments and I am using it too in production and development. I just would like to know if there are any benefits in choosing to pull released images instead?

From my perspective I am setting up every dependent service within `docker-compose` for my app, which I would not have access to anymore if my release pipeline would pull the production image instead. On the other side when I choose to pull the repo I just run `docker-compose up` from my *production* folder and all dependencies are installed - including the dockerized application via Dockerfile.

Comment: In your Dockerfile for your own image, is it `from scratch`? If not, why not pull the upstream base image git repo and build it yourself rather than pulling an already built image?

Comment: This is basically my question - why should I pre build and release my custom application image within ghcr/hub when I could build it directly on my production server including all dependencies?

Comment: I'm turning the question back to you, because I'm fairly certain your Dockerfile isn't only `from scratch`.

Comment: It is not `from scratch`. It is `from ruby`. So let me get you right, you are suggesting pulling the base ruby image and my repository on production and build everything there?

Comment: Nope, I think there's value in using a registry to pull pre-built images, rather than adding that overhead on the production server. That also helps reduce risk that something built in development would build differently in production. It looks like you see that value too, since you aren't building the ruby images yourself.

Comment: Note that "git pull" and "docker pull" are not comparable: one means *get an image*, the other means *get commits and run a second Git command*. It's like trying to compare "buy a truck" to "buy a boat and then drive it across the lake": they're both vehicles, but they do very different *things*.

Comment: Well if that helps you to understand my question better... when do I drive a boat and when do I drive a truck - but in programming context please. This comment is otherwise at maximum philosophical, as I mentioned that I am building the image even if I pull the repository...

Answer (score 1):

There many reasons, lets pick up some of them:

1. **Docker images are not just code**
   A docker-images contains **all** the stuff, which is necessary for an application. That can be a specific version of java, php or other dependencies and binaries (`ping` is a good example).
2. **Docker images are prebuilt**
   In a git-repository is only code. That means: There are no dependencies in there. If you want to run that code in production, then the production-server must download all dependencies - which can be a lot, especially with `npm` - and then it have to build it. The building-process can take a long time and needs a lot of resources (CPU-time, memory, io, ...). Resources that are not useable for your users while the server is building.
3. **Docker containers are isolated**
   What happens if you want to run different applications on the same server? Spring Boot applications a running per default on port `8080`. A port is an exclusive resource, which can be only used by one process.
4. **Docker images are versioned**
   You can define versions for images like `node:16`. Yes, you can get that in `git` with tags, but versions are a lot easier.
5. **It is not only docker**
   There is a change at servers. [Bare metal servers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bare-metal_server) are dying, today we're using clusters. Clusters which can be autoscaled out-of-the-box. A very short startup-time for applications is necessary. And that is not possible with git.
6. **many more**

Comment: Point 5 is a valid answer for my question! The other points are just explanations for docker and docker vs. bare metal servers. Which are off topic as I mentioned that in both cases I am using docker... At least I got something, thank you for your effort!